# NOICONS switch in Inno setup tool not working

Tags: inno-setup

I am have installed innosetup-5.5.9-unicode.exe on windows 8.

I wrote an application say demo

when I try to install

c:\demo-2.0-x86.exe /NOICONS <== It is getting installed with out any issue, but as per Inno tool documentation

/NOICONS
Instructs Setup to initially check the Don't create a Start Menu folder check box on the Select Start Menu Folder wizard page.

But its still creates shortcuts and is visible in Start Menu Folder.

Do we have any workaround for this ? or need to write some extra code ?

Comment: Show us a log file and some screenshots.

Comment: By setting
DisableProgramGroupPage=auto
AllowNoIcons=yes

Every thing is working fine, so no issues 

c:\demo-2.0-x86.exe /NOICONS works now

Comment: Please, post it as an answer or delete your question.